# Why are there multiple threads going on here?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I setup the BugNet project (http://www.bugnetproject.com/) and I am wanting to customize it.  Unfortunately, I don't know a whole lot about asp (my background is WinForms, but I have done some limited work with asp in the past).

Anyway, I set a break point in the method below and as I am stepping through it I see that this method is being called a ridiculous (in my uneducated opinion) number of times.  It seems to me that as the application starts it should just be called once.  And to be clear, it's not finishing and then being called again, but rather there are many threads going on at the same time.

My question is this:  Is this normal behavior for a project like this?  Do Asp.net Web Form projects naturally call this method many times, and if not how should I go about figuring out why it keeps getting called?

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var app = (HttpApplication)sender;
        var context = app.Context;

        // Attempt to perform first request initialization
        Initialization.Init(context);

        if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().Contains("bugdetail.aspx"))
        {
            Response.Redirect(string.Format("~/Issues/IssueDetail.aspx{0}", Request.Url.Query));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN states:

> Occurs as the first event in the HTTP pipeline chain of execution when ASP.NET responds to a request.

To every request, not the first one. You should think about it as a Begin of the Request, not the Application itself. And an Application may of course have a lot of requests, for resources for example.

Comment: Ok, so would you be able to give me any insight as to how I might figure out where it's asking for said resources?  In my limited knowledge, the Application_BeginRequest is the closest thing to the first line of code that gets run when I start the project... where else should I be looking?

Comment: When your browser loads a page, it asks for main page, images, css, javascript and so on. Each such request is processed through pipeline, so BeginRequest is triggered. In short: it is the browser that is asking for resources. 
By the way, there is Application_Start event, called at the beginning of the application, it runs only once when the application first time runs.

Answer (score 0):

The `Application_BeginRequest` is called on every asp.net request, not only asp.net pages, but also handlers, maybe images if you set it, other resource, etc.

Let see what happens here. The browser is request at the same time from the web server many resource, at least 4 at the same time, the page that is the main request, and then scripts, handlers, images, and other...

When you debug this point, the browser is send many request at ones, and IIS use threads to replay to them as soon as possible. So here is the multithread that you see... and yes is normal, the BeginRequest is signaling on any asp.net request, not only the page.aspx